# How to remove only the last word from a file

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I created the following Perl one-liner in order to remove a word from a file

This Perl also escapes special characters such as `@` or `$` or `*`, so every word that contains a special character will removed from the file.

How to change the Perl syntax in order to delete only the last matched word from a file and not all the words?

Example

```
 more file

 Kuku
 Toto
 Kuku
 kuku
```

```
export REPLACE_NAME="Kuku"
export REPLACE_WITH=""
perl -i -pe 'next if /^#/; s/(^|\s)\Q$ENV{REPLACE_NAME }\E(\s|$)/$1$ENV{ REPLACE_WITH }$2/'  file
```

expected results

```
 more file
 Kuku
 Toto
 Kuku
```

another example

when - **export REPLACE_NAME="mark@$!"**

```
more file

mark@$!
hgst#@
hhfdd@@
```

expected results

```
hgst#@
hhfdd@@
```

Comment: Last line of the file or last word of the file?

Comment: last word in the file

Comment: So your file is having one word in the last line always or it has more words?

Comment: Using awk and tac. `tac file | awk '!x{x=sub(/(.*)kuku/,"\1")}1' | tac`

Comment: If you always want to remove the last word then what is `export REPLACE_NAME="Kuku "` for? Do you actually want to remove the last occurrence of `Kuku`, which may be before the last line of the file or may not appear at all?

Comment: Ha , the Kuku is only example , I run this perl in the loop so REPLACE_NAME will get every cycle different word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File) to make this easier.

```
$ perl -MTie::File -E'tie @file, "Tie::File", shift or die $!; $file[-1] =~ s/\b\Q$ENV{REPLACE_NAME}\E\b/$ENV{REPLACE_WITH}/' file
```

**Update:** Rewriting as a program in order to explain it.

```
# Load the Tie::File module
use Tie::File;

# Tie::File allows you to create a link between an array and a file,
# so that any changes you make to the array are reflected in file.
# The "tie()" function connects the file (passed as an argument and
# therefore accessible using shift()) to a new array (called @file).
tie my @file, 'Tie::File', shift
  or die $!;

# The last line of the file will be in $file[-1].
# We use s/.../.../ to make a substitution on that line.
$file[-1] =~ s/\b\Q$ENV{REPLACE_NAME}\E\b/$ENV{REPLACE_WITH}/;
```

**Update:** So now you've changed you requirements spec. You want to remove the last occurrence of the string, which is not necessarily on the last line of the file.

Honestly, I think you've moved past the kind of task that I'd write in command-line switches. It'd write a separate program that looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', shift
  or die $!;

foreach (reverse @file) {
  if (s/\b\Q$ENV{REPLACE_NAME}\E\b/$ENV{REPLACE_WITH}/) {
    last;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please give little explain about your new syntax?

Comment: Done. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: thank you ,       I get - Unrecognized switch: -Etie @file, "Tie::File", shift or die; $file[-1] =~ s/\b\Q$ENV{REPLACE_NAME}\E\b/$ENV{REPLACE_WITH}/  (-h will show valid options).  ( my perl version  v5.8.8 , )

Comment: Sorry, I'm in the habit of using `-E` as it does the same as `-e` but also turns on all of the Perl 5.10+ features. In this case `-e` will work just as well. But perhaps consider upgrading to a version of Perl that isn't ten years old!

Comment: `$!` works fine with the `tie` to this module, so you can say `or die $!`

Comment: @Eytan: *"excellent answer"* I agree. I often get flack if I recommend `Tie::File` because it's very slow, but the resulting code is usually so concise that I think it's an excellent choice unless you're dealing with multi-megabytes files

Comment: Should be `$ENV{REPLACE_WITH}` not `$REPLACE_WITH`, no?

Comment: hi Dave - i try it today on my linux machine but it not  remove the word , can you please check it again

Comment: What (exactly) did you try? What (exactly) was the result? Did you see any error messages?

Comment: no error - I just run the perl line with the file as in my example but the "Kuku" word not removed from the file

Comment: did you try to run it on your linux machine?

Comment: I tested it under Cygwin on Windows. Moving it to Linux will make no difference. I suspect that your file is not the same as the one I tested with.

Comment: my file is very simple -->  Kuku
 Toto
 Kuku
 kuku    and I run the perl as --> perl -MTie::File -e'tie @file, "Tie::File", shift or die $!; $file[-1] =~ s/\b\Q$ENV{REPLACE_NAME}\E\b/$ENV{REPLACE_WITH}/' file

Comment: Ha I see the problem - actually I want to replace the last match word , and the perl line replace only the last

Comment: can I update my question about - to remove the last match word ?

Comment: another issue is if I change the word to Kuku@$ , then it not remove that , this perl target is to remove evry kind of characters

Comment: Hi dave - first thx a lot , because I want to run this perl from a bash script can you please convert it to perl one liner

Comment: As I said, this is more complex than I'm comfortable running as a one-liner, so I'm not going to do that for you. To run it from a bash script, I'd put my code in a file (called, say, `replace_names`) and then call it as `replace_names file`.